# How can I install Drush without Composer?

Tags: drush, composer

I've been trying to install Drush for a while but have failed. I have no experience in command line applications.

I've seen quite a few tutorials:

- https://www.drupal.org/node/594744
- https://www.drupal.org/node/2405811
- https://drupalize.me/videos/wonderful-world-composer
- https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#installation-windows

but each one says that Composer is required. The catch, I can't seem to get Composer to work either.

Would I ever be able to install Drush, but still work around installing Composer?

Specifications:

1. Windows 10
2. Drupal 8.1.8
3. Cpanel 56.0.33
4. Php 5.59 (or higher according to [this](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/system-requirements/overview))
5. Composer Manager 8x-10-rc

Answer (score 6):

This is the simplest solution I have found.

If you don't want to use composer, follow the instructions here...

https://sharpi.sh/blog/web-development/install-drush-on-ubuntu-quickly-without-composer/

1. Download a Drush release from Github to user folder

`wget https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/releases/download/8.1.17/drush.phar`

2. Rename drush.phar to drush

`mv drush.phar drush`

3. Find the bin directory

`echo $PATH`

which shows something like.... /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games

I’ll go with /usr/local/bin

4. Move drush to the bin

`mv drush /usr/local/bin/drush`

5. Change permissions to

`chmod +x /usr/local/bin/drush`

6. Test with

`drush version`

Comment: OP is on Windows...

Comment: Isn’t it advised to install Drush to the project level now and optionally install Drush Wrapper? Anyway if user is on Windows, `wget` isn’t going to work without additional steps. Better off with composer.

Comment: Sorry, stuck this here for my own sanity more than anything. Some people don't want to use composer https://www.ostraining.com/blog/coding/composer-cms/

Answer (score 1):

Just follow the installation instructions on http://docs.drush.org/en/8.x/install/ No need for Composer to use Drush 8.

PS! Drush 9 is meant to be installed site local - as part of your Drupal installation - using Composer.