# Upgrade to Devel 8.x-2.0 without Composer

Tags: composer

I have Devel 8.x-1.2 installed and need to upgrade to 8.x-2.0 but I cannot install Composer/Drush on the server as it is not included in the hosted service.
Any guidance how can I execute this upgrade?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I install Drush without Composer?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/212274/how-can-i-install-drush-without-composer). See the answer by Jaypan.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Click the tarball or zip file link, extract folder. Upload devel folder to /modules folder.

Then run **update.php** by going to `yourwebsite.com/update.php` and then flush all caches.

> Note that if the module requires any external dependencies this will
>   not work.

Indeed, I don't believe this is the case for Devel. But if your module has external dependencies and must be installed via composer. Simply in a local or some other environment install it using composer and then upload all the files that were installed, including the /vendor directory files.

Comment: Note that if the module requires any external dependencies this will not work.

Comment: It depends on symfony/var-dumper (which might already be there as a dependency of something else)

Comment: Thank you . I will have a check if this could work. Just need to be careful with overwriting existing files so will take a copy first.